# Primefaces: Datatable filter event ajax issues

Tags: jsf, primefaces

when I am trying to add a filter event to my primefaces datatable as follows:

```
<p:dataTable class="bodyWidth" id="dataTable" var="user" value="#{userTable.userModel}" ...>

  <p:ajax event="filter" update="@(#dtSummary)"/>

  <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />
  <p:column .../>
</p:dataTable>
```

I get the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: loader constraint violation in
>   interface itable initialization: when resolving method
>   "**org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(Ljavax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent**;)V"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class,
>   **org/primefaces/component/behavior/ajax/AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl**, and
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for
>   interface **javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorListener** have different Class
>   objects for the type
>   **iorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(Ljavax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent**;)V
>   used in the signature

Is this a well-known bug or something wrong with project setup? By the way. Other event types like rowEdit work fine.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Did you try `update="@([id=dtSummary])"`?

Comment: it doesn't work as well :/ probably the issue is located on another part... still analyzing it.

Comment: @JohnRumpel Did you sort this out? This usually indicates having multiple versions of the same class present in the classpath, confusing the class loading mechanism. Are you using maven?

Comment: I'm currently building by using native eclipse. This is ant internally, isn't it?